# Handling Concurrency Exception When Using UpdateRange Method

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, concurrency, ef-core-2.0

first of all i get a tracked list of items from Database(Sql Server).
I have a scenario to Update list of items with concurrency checking. 
every row in database have the rowversion Column and is configured with fluent api IsRowversion() Method.

after editing some properties for each item in list, with a breakpoint I change one column by hand for each of rows in sql server to throw the exception.
but the exception always has just one entry even with multiple records changes.
(Ef core 2.1)

```
public async Task UpdateWithConcurrency<T>(List<T> items, CancellationToken ct) where T : class, new()
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            item.GetType().GetProperty("DateModified").SetValue(item, DateTime.Now);

        List<T> databaseEntries = new List<T>();
        _context.UpdateRange(items);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(ct);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            var errors = ex.Entries; // ==> The count is always one even 
            // even with changes in each row

            foreach (var errorEntry in errors)
            {
                var databaseItem = await errorEntry.GetDatabaseValuesAsync();
                databaseEntries.Add(databaseItem.ToObject() as T);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the exception always has just one entry even with multiple records changes. (Ef core 2.1)

SaveChanges() runs in a transaction, but applies the changes one-at-a-time.  EF does not continue to try to save changes after the first concurrency error.

Comment: I Imagined that it wraps all of the changes. so the entries has always one object. but how to handle multiple updates ?